Can't load my YOLOv8n model, trained on custom dataset
I use Ultralytics YOLOv8 with the model, trained on custom dataset, and run the following python code:
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("/home/github/ultralytics/ultralytics/runs/detect/train3/weights/best.pt")

and get this error:
requirements: YOLOv8 requirement "ultralytics.nn.modules.conv" not found, attempting AutoUpdate...
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ultralytics.nn.modules.conv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ultralytics.nn.modules.conv
requirements: ❌ Command 'pip install "ultralytics.nn.modules.conv"  ' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Tried to run :
pip install --upgrade ultralytics 

Tried different conda Python environment (v3.8.8, v3.10.14), and got the same results

can you try this : https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/3808#issuecomment-1815172389 ?

I suggest you update to Python 3.12.6.

Solution from https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/3808#issuecomment-1815172389 did not work

I've created the new conda environment with Python 3.12.5, installed everything from the scratch, and it works now! Thanks for the help

I've created the new conda environment with Python 3.12.5, installed everything from the scratch, and it works now! Thanks for the help
